# Will oomph help me update my Mars Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I have Eclipse Mars 2 running under Ubuntu. When Neon becomes the current release, will **oomph** help me update my installed version to Neon, without importing projects into a new workspace? Or will just the 'check for updates' prove sufficient for the task, without my changing th repositories available?

Answer (score 3):

When updating to a new version of Eclipse, you never need to create a new workspace; new versions can load and use wokspaces from previous versions.

For Neon, there has been a fundamental structural change in the packages that you can download or that Oomph typically installs, and unfortunately they are not updatable from Mars. The new structure will allow more granular updates to the packages in the future, a long-desired feature, so a tradeoff had to be made. If you're interested in the gory details, check out [this explanation](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/epp-dev/msg03947.html).

This means that it won't be possible to upgrade an installation of a Mars package to a Neon package.<sup>*</sup> But like I said, it's easy enough to install the new Neon and then use it to open your existing workspace; all your projects and workspace layout & preferences will be there.

---

<sup>*</sup>If you have *not* used one of the packages (99% of users *have*), instead built your own installation up from the core Platform, then you could theoretically upgrade - but very few people other than developers of Eclipse ever do that.

Comment: Thank you, that's most useful. I've not long moved from a Windows environment to Ubuntu. I installed Eclipse using the new (to me) installer, extracted  from eclipse-inst-linux64.tar.gz. It created a home/eclipse/jee-mars folder. I'm hoping that when neon is released, then a new version of the installer will create a folder home/eclipse/jee-neon, alongside the existing mars one. AM I correct in assuming this?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the installer allows you to choose where the installation is placed. But the answer to the heart of your question is, "Yes, Neon will be installed alongside any existing Eclipse installations you have."

Comment: There is a technical detail about that, namely that the Oomph installer uses bundle pooling so the bundles for your Mars installation might be placed together with the Neon bundles. But that's not really visible or important to the average IDE user.

Comment: As I only have a handful of projects and the package structure is changed between Mars and Neon. I think it would be best to backup my workspace, delete ~/eclipse, ~/.eclipse and ./.p2, then install Neon from scratch after the 22nd. I only have the C/C++, php and Swing builders plus the Mongrel/Tomcat to add.  Plus the Java IDE of course. What do you think?

Comment: Other than to save some disk space, I don't see any reason to delete those folders. Backing up your workspace is a good idea; just in the remote chance that you don't like or can't use Neon, to make sure your Mars can still use that workspace.